# Why do people use present tense when they are quoting someone?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, conversation, quoting

I've heard and used this a lot but was wondering why and is it even correct.

When you are in a conversation with your mates and you are telling a story and when you try to quote someone, you say

> "and he goes 'Oh, I run marathons, too'. "

Why do we use present tense there? Can it be

> "and he went 'Oh, I run marathons, too'. "

Is it a grammatically correct English?

Comment: This isn’t about quoting people – it’s just the historical present (also called the dramatic present or the narrative present). It could just as well have been, “And then he takes out his phone and snaps a photo” instead. There are a few questions about the historical present on here; this is more or less a duplicate of [What is the historic present tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235910/what-is-the-historic-present-tense), though the answer given there isn’t stellar.

Comment: That makes sense! I read the definition on Wiki! Thanks

Comment: *He goes* is an informal, almost slang, idiom. It has nothing to do with tenses per se. It's a set phrase, and can be used to mean either *he says* or *he said.* Strangely, *he went* is also used—although it's difficult to not interpret that one in the past tense specifically.

Comment: Wait so is it because it's a slang or a historical present? @JasonBassford

Comment: @GoldSkullwithPattern To me, if something is an idiom, that trumps everything else. However, it's certainly possible to look at it both ways. And I can't *quite* class this as an idiom, because it's context dependent. If it's not followed by speech, then normal grammar applies: *He goes to the store.*